# Git commit API for GitHub Enterprise private repositories

Tags: git, api, github

I've been digging in the [GitHub api documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository), but I'm still having an issue finding out about GitHub Enterprise private repositories (it's for my company's work).

I did get a result back using a regular person GitHub account using this link:
`https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits` so I changed the owner to my company and repo name, but I just got this back.

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository"
}
```

So the questions I have:

1. How to get access to GitHub Enterprise repo APIs?
2. Would visitors require a GitHub account to view this page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to contact your company's GitHub Enterprise Server instances, you don't want to use https://api.github.com, since that's for GitHub Cloud (github.com). Instead, as mentioned in [the documentation for GitHub Enterprise Server](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.17/v3/), you'll want to use `https://hostname/api/v3` (where `hostname` is your server's hostname).

So if your company's server were example.com and you were looking up the repository `octocat/spoon-knife`, your request would go to `https://example.com/api/v3/repos/octocat/spoon-knife/commits`.

Note that you may require authentication for this request, depending on the repository; if the repository requires authentication and you lack it, you'll get a 404 response, even if the repository actually exists.